# java issue with date

Tags: java, date

I have a problem in java with sql date. I have the value of year-y, month-m,day-d I create new Date(y,m,d) but it says that this constructor is deprecated and it returns wrong date,
how can I correctly set date, having y,m,d ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29),

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date)
>   or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900,
>   month, date).

Comment: can i change the value of year ?

Comment: @Vahan: _Calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1900)_ is this what you mean? I'm a little confused...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `public Date(long date)` where `date` is the number of **milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT**

In your case you can also use:

```
Date mydate = Date.valueOf("2011-05-04"); // yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: how can i get long Date, having year, month day ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can convert between the two:

```
new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, date);

Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: in this case cannot convert from java.util.date to sql.date

Answer (score 1):

Use the Calendar class:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, date);
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
```

Then if you have to use dates, then you can do the following -

```
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: in this case cannot convert from java.util.date to sql.date